# software raid mirror verification

Tags: raid

I am created the raid 1 mirror , I have made two partitions in in single hard drive they are sdc1 and sdc2, my question is how to verify that data is being written in both drives and how can I know out of sdc1 and sdc2  how to write particular partition

Comment: This is handled by your raid hardware's firmware and/or raid software.  Your question is not clear.

Comment: I just want to verify that In raid mirror data is being written in both the partitions sdc1 and sdc2 which are member of raid set, but I don't know the way.

Comment: This isn't something you should worry about.  This is something that is handled by either the RAID hardware your using itself or the RAID software if your implementing a software based RAID setup.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention if this is hardware RAID or software RAID.  Since both partitions are on the same hard drive I'm going to assume it's software RAID.

Most software RAID solutions will have a method of testing the data replication between partitions.  For example, raidtools has a "raidsetfaulty" command.  Here's an example of how you might use it:

```
raidsetfaulty /dev/md1 /dev/sdc2
```

should be enough to fail the disk /dev/sdc2 of the array /dev/md1. If you are using mdadm, just type

```
mdadm --manage --set-faulty /dev/md1 /dev/sdc2
```

Now things move up and fun appears. First, you should see something like the first line of this on your system's log. Something like the second line will appear if you have spare disks configured.

```
kernel: raid1: Disk failure on sdc2, disabling device. 
kernel: md1: resyncing spare disk sdb7 to replace failed disk
```

Checking /proc/mdstat out will show the degraded array. If there was a spare disk available, reconstruction should have started.

Source: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Software-RAID-HOWTO-6.html

Comment: Thank you for the solution, and I have another question to ask, that is : After creating the raid 1  md0 using sdb1 and sdb2  and formating to ext4  and mount to mount point and writing some data to it.now is there any way to mount only single member sdb1 or sdb2 of raid  and access data. thank you

Comment: You can try to assemble the RAID array with only one drive.  If you're using mdadm the command would be `madadm -A /dev/sdb1`.  You might check out this similar, but slightly different, question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64889/how-to-mount-recover-data-on-a-disk-that-was-part-of-a-mdadm-raid-1-on-another-m

Comment: If the answer helped or was correct, don't forget to mark it as correct or upvote it.